# R: Index to unique vector that returns original

Tags: r, indexing, unique

I have a vector `v <- c(6,8,5,5,8)` of which I can obtain the unique values using

```
> u <- unique(v)
> u
[1] 6 8 5
```

Now I need an index `i = [2,3,1,1,3]` that returns the original vector `v` when indexed into `u`.

```
> u[i]
[1] 6,8,5,5,8
```

I know such an index can be generated automatically in Matlab, [the ci index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html#outputarg_ic), but does not seem to be part of the standard repertoire in R. Is anyone aware of a function that can do this?

The background is that I have several vectors with anonymized IDs that are long character strings:

```
ids
"PTefkd43fmkl28en==3rnl4"
"cmdREW3rFDS32fDSdd;32FF"
"PTefkd43fmkl28en==3rnl4"
"PTefkd43fmkl28en==3rnl4"
"cmdREW3rFDS32fDSdd;32FF"
```

To reduce the file size and simplify the code, I want to transform them into integers of the sort

```
ids
1
2
1
1
2
```

and found that the index of the unique vector does just this. Since there are many rows, I am hesitant to write a function that loops over each element of the unique vector and wonder whether there is a more efficient way — or a completely different way to transform the character strings into matching integers.

Comment: You can use `match` i.e. `match(v, u)` or `findInterval(v,u)`.  BTW, the `unique(v)` returns output as `6 8 5` assuming that you did `sort` to create `u`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `match`

```
 df1$ids <- with(df1, match(ids, unique(ids)) )
 df1$ids
 #[1] 1 2 1 1 2
```

Or we can convert to `factor` and coerce to `numeric`

```
 with(df1,as.integer(factor(ids, levels=unique(ids))))
 #[1] 1 2 1 1 2
```

Using `u` and `v`.  Based on the output of 'u' in the OP's post, it must have been `sort`ed

```
 u <- sort(unique(v))
 match(v, u)
 #[1] 2 3 1 1 3
```

Or using `findInterval`.  Make sure that 'u' is sorted.

```
 findInterval(v,u)
 #[1] 2 3 1 1 3
```